# Can i write this Query in ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

for a data analysis i need both results into one set.

```
a.follower_trackings.pluck(:date, :new_followers, :deleted_followers)
a.data_trackings.pluck(:date, :followed_by_count)
```

instead of ugly-merging an array (they can have different starting dates and i obv. need only those values where the date exists in both arrays) i thought about mysql

```
SELECT 
  followers.new_followers, 
  followers.deleted_followers, 
  trackings.date, 
  trackings.followed_by_count 
FROM 
  instagram_user_follower_trackings AS followers, 
  instagram_data_trackings AS trackings 
WHERE 
  followers.date = trackings.date 
  AND 
    followers.user_id=5 
  AND 
    trackings.user_id=5 
ORDER 
  BY trackings.date DESC
```

This is Working fine, but i wonder if i can write the same with ActiveRecord?

Comment: I think you'll have to do two queries with activerecord because it is based on model

Comment: What are the relation types between `a`, `follower_trackings` and `data_trackings`?

Comment: @Uzbekjon `a has_many follower_trackings` and `a has_many data_trackings`. the trackings have only relations to `a`

Comment: @PetrGazarov, 2 querys needs to be avoided. then i rather stick with my raw sql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following which should render the same query as your raw SQL, but it's also quite ugly...:

```
a.follower_trackings.
  merge(a.data_trackings).
  from("instagram_user_follower_trackings, instagram_data_trackings").
  where("instagram_user_follower_trackings.date = instagram_data_trackings.date").
  order(:date => :desc).
  pluck("instagram_data_trackings.date", 
         :new_followers, :deleted_followers, :followed_by_count)
```

There are a few tricks turned out useful while playing with the scopes: the [`merge` trick](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/SpawnMethods/merge) adds the `data_trackings.user_id = a.id` condition but it does not join in the `data_trackings`, that's why the `from` clause has to be added, which essentially performs the INNER JOIN. The rest is pretty straightforward and leverages the fact that `order` and `pluck` clauses do not need the table name to be specified if the columns are either unique among the tables, or are specified in the SELECT (`pluck`).

Well, when looking again, I would probably rather define a **scope for retrieving the data for a given user** (`a` record) that would essentially use the raw SQL you have in your question. I might also define a helper instance method that would call the scope with `self`, something like:

```
def Model
  scope :tracking_info, ->(user) { ... }

  def tracking_info
    Model.tracking_info(self)
  end
end
```

Then one can use simply:

```
a = Model.find(1)
a.tracking_info
# => [[...], [...]]
```